# Homology groups of the set with Mayer-Veitoris

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

i need some help please
my professor asked for

> > homology groups of $S^2\cup d$ which $d={\{ (0,0,t) \mid -1 \leq t \leq 1}\}  $ .

We just find homology groups with some points and Mayor-veitoris and CW-complex structures. 
For solving this problemوi thought we can take $S^2/(0,0,0)$ as $u$ and $d/(0,0,0)$ as $v$ in M-V theorem.We know $\mathbb R^3$ is contractible and if we look at $d$ as a subset of $\mathbb R^3$ ,could i say that $v$ is contractible and is homotope with a point?
please guide me for taking $u$ and $v$ or making right CW-Complex for this and let me know that is the intersection between them  homotope with a point or not, please...

Thanks in Advance

Comment: why not go full cw complex? I mean you got a nice line ($d$) and a sphere, which should give you a nice CW skeleton with: 2 cells in the 0-skeleton, 2 3 cells in the 1 skeleton, and 2 cells in the 2 skeleton.
you can also use mayer vietoris, but in my opinion that would be a little overkill, especially since your approach doesn't even exploint the fact that one thingy of your covering is a sphere (of which you most likely already know the homology)
So if you want to use mayer vietoris, I would suggest covering your space by the sphere and by $d$, both having nice homology!

Comment: The Mayer Vietoris sequence works fine, but you do need to know what the maps are in degree zero in order to compute $H_1(X)$. A cellular approach also works: note that your space is homotopy equivalent to a sphere with north and south pole identified, so you can use one 0-cell, two 1-cells and two 2-cells.

Comment: @Enkidu you know ,identify the CW_complex is always fuzzy for me so i like to solve these types of problems with M-V.but your guidness was helpful too

Comment: @Enkidu you know ,identify the CW_complex is always fuzzy for me so i like to solve these types of problems with M-V.but your guidness was helpful too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$If you want to use Mayer-Vietoris, let $A = S^2$ and $B = d$.  Set $X = A \cup B$; then $A \cap B$ is the disjoint union of two points $N$ and $S$ (the north and south poles).  Then
\begin{align*}
    H_k(A) = H_k(S^2) &= \begin{cases} \Z & k=0,2 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}\\
    H_k(B) = H_k(\text{pt}) &= \begin{cases} \Z & k=0 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}\\
    H_k(A \cap B) = H_k(\text{pt}) \oplus H_k(\text{pt}) &= \begin{cases} \Z \oplus \Z & k = 0\\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
\end{align*}
Since $X$ is connected, $H_0(X) = \Z$.  One portion of the Mayer-Vietoris sequence is
$$
    H_2(A \cap B) \longrightarrow H_2(A) \oplus H_2(B) 
    \longrightarrow H_2(X) \longrightarrow H_1(A \cap B)
$$
or
$$
    0 \longrightarrow \Z \oplus 0 \longrightarrow H_2(X) \longrightarrow 0
$$
So we know $H_2(X) = \Z$.  Another portion is
$$
    H_1(A) \oplus H_1(B) \longrightarrow H_1(X) 
    \stackrel{\partial_*}{\longrightarrow} H_0(A \cap B)
    \stackrel{(i_*,j_*)}{\longrightarrow} H_0(A) \oplus H_0(B)
$$
Since $H_1(A) \oplus H_1(B)=0 \oplus 0 = 0$, $\partial_*$ is an injection.  So $H_1(X)$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{im} \partial_* = \ker (i_*,j_*)$.

Now $H_0(A \cap B)$ is a free abelian group on two generators: $[N]$ and $[S]$.  And $H_0(A) \oplus H_0(B)$ is a free abelian group on two generators: $[A]$ and $[B]$.  Since $i$ and $j$ are the inclusion maps from $A \cap B$ to $A$ and $B$, we have
\begin{align*}
    i_*([N]) = i_*([S]) &= [A] \\
    j_*([N]) = j_*([S]) &= [B] \\
\end{align*}
So the kernel of $(i_*,j_*)$ is generated by $[N]-[S]$.  This means $H_1(X) = \Z$.

We can find a generator of $H_1(X)$, too.  Let $c$ be an arc running from $N$ to $S$ along the sphere.  Then $d+c$ is a cycle but not a boundary.  And if you follow the construction, you can see why $\partial_*([d+c]) = [N] - [S]$.

Comment: Awesome answer,thanks a lot it was really helpful.